# Permalink to a comment on azure dev ops (within a pull request)

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there any way to permalink directly to a comment in an azure dev ops pull request (in the way that you can on github)? Url only links to the PR page overall but in sizeable requests this isn't helpful...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still hoping someone flags a native option but in the meantime this chrome plugin provides the functionality if anyone is looking for a quick win:

[Link to Text Fragment](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-to-text-fragment/pbcodcjpfjdpcineamnnmbkkmkdpajjg/related)